# Trying to use PIMS for video analysis, code works on MacOS but not on Windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to run PIMS on my Windows PC, it installs, but returns an error when ran with any MP4 video file. ffmpeg is installed. Always returns the same error "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". I install modules using PIP through the command prompt. This same code runs fine on my Mac. I am using Jupyter Notebook.

I have tried using different MP4 files, I have reinstalled PIMS numerous times.

This is my code:

```
#Modules

%matplotlib inline
import pims
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Video import
video = pims.Video("20190228_2.mp4")

#Seeing information about video
print(video)
print(len(video))
```

And this is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7a95e8e35a9c> in <module>
      1 #Seeing data about video
----> 2 print(video)
      3 print(len(video))

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pims\base_frames.py in __repr__(self)
    174 Pixel Datatype: {dtype}""".format(w=self.frame_shape[0],
    175                                   h=self.frame_shape[1],
--> 176                                   count=len(self),
    177                                   dtype=self.pixel_type)
    178 

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```